# Simple way to randomly choose the name of a JavaScript file from a list of possible names

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-swiffy

I have 170 HTML5 animations that need to be cycled randomly when a page loads.

I figure the easiest thing to do is randomly choose the JavaScript file name for the animation.

Can someone outline easiest way of doing that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I realise that maybe the language I'm using is wrong - am learning as I go.

What I want to do is set the SRC attribute in a SCRIPT tag randomly from a list of 170 filenames.

So far, I've gleaned that it should be something like this,

```
<!--[if !IE]>--><script id="animation" src="" type="text/javascript">
</script> <!--<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
//Files
var filesArray = ['file1.js', 'file2.js'];
//src vars
var url = 'http://www.example.com/';
// Shuffle
var file = musicArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
//Set src
getElementById("animation").src = url + file;
</script>
```

But that's not working for me. Is it even possible to set the SRC attribute in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just populate the **fileNames** array with the filenames and it will generate a random file name.

```
var fileNames = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'],
    fileLen   = fileNames.length;

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(fileNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * fileLen)]);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi Arniekoz,

Thanks a lot for the response. What I'm looking for is a way to populate FILE NAME HERE in this,


`<script src="http://www.example.com/js/[FILE NAME HERE].js" type="text/javascript"></script>`


I understand how to generate the file name randomly using JS, just not how I might then insert the output into the code to complete the javascript file request.